# Do Bounded Partial Sums imply Bounded Summands?

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

Forgive me if this is obvious. Let $(\alpha_n)$ be a complex sequence. If $\left(\sum_{n=0}^N\alpha_n\right)$ is bounded, is it always the case that $(\alpha_n)$ is bounded?

Comment: Hint $\;\alpha_N = \left(\sum_{n=0}^N\alpha_n\right) - \left(\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\alpha_n\right)\,$, so $\,\big|\alpha_N\big| \le \ldots\,$

Comment: @dxiv Of course! If B is the bound on the partial sums, then triangle inequality gives us that 2B is the bound on the summands. Great, thank you!

Comment: Right, that's all there is to it. You may want to post a self-answer for the benefit of future readers.

Comment: @dxiv Is it even worth leaving this post up? It's a pretty trivial question, right?

Comment: That's up to you. FWIW I did not find an exact duplicate to this question on a quick search. As for "trivial", many math things become "trivial" *after* you see them for the first time.

Answer (score 3):

I realized the answer thanks to @dxiv. Suppose $\left(\sum_{n=0}^N\alpha_n\right)$ is bounded. That is, for some $B\geq0,$ all $N\in\mathbb{N}$, $\biggr\lvert\sum_{n=0}^N\alpha_n\biggr\lvert\leq B.$ Then
$$|\alpha_N|=\biggr\lvert\sum_{n=0}^N\alpha_n-\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\alpha_k\biggr\lvert\leq\biggr\lvert\sum_{n=0}^N\alpha_n\biggr\lvert+\biggr\lvert\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\alpha_k\biggr\lvert\leq2B,$$ thus $(\alpha_N)$ is also bounded.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: did not see that you asked for complex sequence, sorry, updated answer slightly.

If there is a constant *upper* bound, yes. One might say that $\sum_{n=0}^{N} n \leq \frac{N(N+1)}{2}$ is a bound, but clearly $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n$ is not bounded. However, if there is a constant upper bound, then we have that $|\sum_{n=0}^{N} a_n| \leq c$ for positive integer $N$, which implies $\lim_{N \to \infty} |\sum_{n=0}^{N} a_n| \leq c$, which means that $|\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n| \leq c$, and hence $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n$ is bounded.

Edit 2: I realized with the help of OP that convergence does not imply bounding, sorry, I have edited my post.

Let me know if you have any additional questions.

Comment: Well I don't think that this implies convergence of the sum, only that it is bounded.

Comment: I'm not sure of the name, but I'm pretty sure there's a theorem that states explicitly that if the partial sums are bounded(and hence the infinite series is bounded) by a constant then the sum converges, I'll try to find it

Comment: Consider Grandi's series 1-1+1-... This is bounded in [0,1] but does not converge.

Comment: Wow, okay, can't believe I didn't remember that. I believe this actually answers your question: Grandi's series has bounded partial sums but does not converge, so the answer to your question is false.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand my question. I'm asking if the partial sums are bounded, is it always true that the summands are bounded. Is $(a_n)$ bounded?

Comment: Ah, so sorry, I thought your question was asking if $a_n$ is convergent; I might have either misread quickly or something similar. Yes, $a_n$ is bounded. I'm so sorry for the confusion.